# writing numbers inside a plot using epilog

Tags: plotting, graphics

I need to write infidelity number $\bar{F}=6.82\times 10^{-6}$ inside a plot. I tried using Epilog with TeXForm but could not succeed. It prints $\frac{1}{10^6}$ instead of $10^{-6}$. Any help? Thanks.

Comment: I didn't get why do you need `TeXForm`, but what you want can be done as simple as: `Plot[Sin[x],{x,0,1}, Epilog -> Text[Row[{OverBar[F], "\[ThinSpace]=\[ThinSpace]", 6.82/10^6}],{0.5,0.5}]]`.

Comment: Thanks. I was using TeXForm because it gives me a nice $\times$ sign. And I would prefer $10^{-6}$ instead of taking it into the denominator (due to lack of vertical space inside the figure).

Comment: TeXForm does not output $\times$. It might output `\times`, but not $\times$. It is unclear what you mean. Do you want to display TeX code? TeXForm produces TeX code. Or do you want to display formatted math? I wrote my answer with the latter in mind, assuming that your question is about how to format the result, not about how to use `Epilog` or `Text`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on the other answers, using `Inset` and `MaTeX`

```
<< MaTeX`
LaTeXStuff = MaTeX["\\bar F = 6.45\\times 10^{-6}"];
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Epilog -> Inset[LaTeXStuff, {4, .5}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use Inset like this:

```
f = 6.82*^-6;

inset = Inset[
   Style[StringForm["F = ``", ScientificForm[f]], 14],
   Scaled[{.65, .75}], Scaled[{.5, .5}], Scaled[.3]
   ];

Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Epilog -> inset]
```

[image]

Kind regards,

David

Answer (score 1):

Method 1:

- Type in a string such as `"x"`.
- Select the `x` only. Convert to TraditionalForm (on macOS, Command-Shift-T)
- Press Left-Arrow, then delete the x and start typing: F Ctrl-7 _ Right-Arrow 6.82 Esc * Esc 10 Ctrl-6 -6 Right-Arrow

Method 2:

```
TraditionalForm@HoldForm[OverBar[F] == 6.45*^-6]
```

Method 3:

Use [MaTeX](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/MaTeX).

```
<< MaTeX`

MaTeX["\\bar F = 6.45\\times 10^{-6}"]
```